# what compiler does internally for initializing a variable and assigning a variable while constructing object?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why should I prefer to use member initialization list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926752/why-should-i-prefer-to-use-member-initialization-list)

Class A has a member variable i.  i can be initialized  or assigned during object creation.

A) Initialise

```
   class A {
         int i;
    public:
        A(int _i) : i(_i){}
    }
```

B) assign

```
class A {
         int i;
    public:
        A(int _i) : { i = _i}
    }
```

My question is what is the basic difference between these 2 approach?

Comment: For simple POD types like `int`? Nothing.

Comment: Not the same question, but might be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926752/why-should-i-prefer-to-use-member-initialization-list

Comment: @Corbin Yes, it's not the same question, but it answers this one quite fully. Short version: A is better for member class initialization and is the only way to initialize `const` members.

Comment: A is initialization, B is assignment.

Answer (score 2):

The difference lies in which C++ mechanism is used to initialize `i` in your class.  Case (A) initializes it via constructor, and case (B) uses the assignment operator (or a copy constructor if no assignment operator is defined).

Most C++ compilers would generate exactly the same code for this particular example, because you're using int, which is a "plain old data" type.  If `i` were a class type, it could make a great deal of difference.

Comment: at this point object has not been created so copy contr or assignment operator is not available here

Comment: @user966379 - I was referring to the constructor or assignment operator for `i` alone, not `A`.  Since `i` is of type `int`, the constructor or assignment operator for an `int` are used when initializing that particular member of your class, whether your entire class is ready yet or not.